# jquery Input field pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JQUERY. I have an requirement like based on the input, the same input field needs to be altered without submitting the form.

If number starts with 33 or 55 or 81, display as (xx) xxxx-xxxx, for everything other number pattern should be (xxx) xxx-xxxx.

Could anyone help me on this.

I tried this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Validation</h1>

<input id="phone" type="number">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var twoNumbers = $(this).attr("phone").substr(0, 2);
    if(twoNumbers == 33 || twoNumbers == 55 || twoNumbers == 81){
        $("#phone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
    }else{
        $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please correct this html

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @PraveenKumar- Let me clarify this more: There is an input field. When I enter mobile numbers starting with 33 or 55 or 81, I should start displaying those numbers in (xx)xxxx-xxxx format. Other numbers will be displayed as (xxx)xxx-xxxx without submitting the form

Comment: That's what I am saying. Any one of the jQuery plugin for input mask will do: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ - Check this out.

Comment: @PraveenKumarI have shared the html code, please help me

Comment: Following the link, I started coding.. But struck in middle

Comment: Okay, I will help you.

Comment: Mark, kindly check my answer again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is perfect, but can you please attach it to the `keyup` event of the textbox? Also it is `$(this).val().substr(0, 2);` not the one you used. Please make sure you are putting the mask only when the input is `> 2` characters.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#phone").keyup(function () {
      $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
      if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
        var twoNumbers = $(this).val().substr(0, 2);
        if (twoNumbers == 33 || twoNumbers == 55 || twoNumbers == 81) {
          console.log("First: " + twoNumbers);
          $("#phone").inputmask({
            mask: "(99) 9999-9999"
          });
        } else {
          console.log("Second: " + twoNumbers);
          $("#phone").inputmask({
            mask: "(999) 999-9999"
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/fujunojelu**

Comment: But, the change is not happening in text field

Comment: @MarkNicholas Actually the problem is with the Plugin: `Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not support selection.`

Comment: I am trying to fix it.

Comment: You might need [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask)'s dynamic option: `$(selector).inputmask("9-a{1,3}9{1,3}"); //mask with dynamic syntax`

Comment: I am not getting it. Can you please give a working script

Comment: @MarkNicholas Please will you wait? I am working on it. `:)`

Comment: @MarkNicholas Check out the answer buddy. It works perfectly.

Comment: @MarkNicholas Welcome buddy. `:)`

Comment: a small issue.. the conditional check is not working as expected. i.e, If first two digits are 33, then it should be in format (99) 9999-9999

Comment: @MarkNicholas Instead of `> 2` change it to `> 3`?

Comment: @MarkNicholas Lemme check.

Comment: @MarkNicholas Sorry sorry. It's totally wrong. Do this: `== 2` and it works... Sorry again...

Comment: Sorry dude, making it to ==2 doesnt provide actual result for other scenarios

Comment: @MarkNicholas It is gonna be 12 am in UK buddy... Need to sleep. Is it really okay if I do it tomorrow morning? Sorry about that.

Comment: Sure, Please give a solution tomorrow

Comment: @MarkNicholas Sure... First thing in the morning... `:)`

Comment: You have any idea how this could be accomplished?

Comment: Whats that dude.. can you please give me a working script

Comment: @MarkNicholas Man... Still working on the right one... Give me a few mins... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Why invent the weel, you have it already. You can accomplish this with one of the already made jquery plugins.

This is one of them:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Download it and upload it to your server.
Put the reference to the plugin in the head of your page:

```
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can now mask the inputs in the way you like:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999", {placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy"});
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
   $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
   $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
});
```

I understand You want to do some conditional masking, as if number starts with 85. If you also need help for this, please post also your HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.. This Code works well for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.catcher.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Mobile Number Formatting</h3>
<input id="phone" type="text">
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#phone").keyup(function () {
      $(this).attr("phone", $(this).val());
        var twoNumbers = $(this).val().substr(0, 3);
        if (twoNumbers == '(33' || twoNumbers == '(55' || twoNumbers == '(81') {
          $("#phone").inputmask({
            mask: "(99) 9999-9999"
          });
        } else {
          $("#phone").inputmask({
            mask: "(999) 999-9999"
          });
        }
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

use event blur for input then format the value of input value according to the required pattern

```
$("#InputID").blur(function() {

    $(this).val() // check if input value is equal required pattern use any format JS plugin  
});
```