# How to validate a form field in format - 00.000.000.0-000.000

Tags: php, forms, validation, redux-form-validators

I am creating a form in PHP and in my form I have a field "TAX ID". This field should have value in this format only - "00.000.000.0-000.000"

Any suggestion how to achieve validation in this format for "TAX ID" field ??

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery Input field pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111010/jquery-input-field-pattern)

Comment: Hello, please read more about jQuery patterns: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: thanks for commenting - I will check this - should we use regex expression for this ?
also i need to validate this as well - like if customer not type correct value show an error - please suggest

Comment: You need to make the pattern first, and then if the input isn't matching the pattern you can show the errors

Comment: yes @BurhanKashour - I am somewhere struggling on how to create a pattern like this.

Comment: What language you want to use to manipulate the data?

Comment: I am using php - but can validate using jquery

Comment: I have made you a simple pattern: https://regexr.com/5f5i5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use regex
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_regex.asp

```
<?php
$str = "Visit W3Schools";
$pattern = "/w3schools/i";
echo preg_match($pattern, $str); //this is true
?>
```

for example

```
/[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]/
```